# Print Binary using recursion

Tags: java, recursion

This code work properly. I need help to change this into int function. Please don't add extra **int or void function** to it.

```
public void binary(int n) {
    if(n==0)
        return;

    binary(n>>1);
    System.out.printf("%d",n%2);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Can you explain a bit more or show the expected output you want? Thanks.

Comment: @ggorlen I think he wants his function to return `binary of a number` as `int`. Eg: `2` should `10` as `int`.

Comment: Hmm, seems pretty easy to overflow with that strategy. Anyway, I don't see an attempt here at making the conversion but as a hint, multiply by 10 to move on to the next digit in the result.

Comment: @ggorlen That is true

Comment: yes this code for print binary using recursion but the problem is how I change this void to int  by changes some line to the code. otherwise I can create and call other function to give answer in int but this way increases my space complexity . So please change this function to int

Comment: Instead of asking us to do it, the typical approach is to try it yourself, then ask for help _with your attempt_.

Comment: I tried but I'm not getting that perfect approach.

Comment: We assume you didn't get your code perfect. Otherwise you wouldn't be asking for help with your homework problem. We would like to see this code so we can help you with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the changed code:

```
public int binary(int n)
{
    if (n == 0 || n == 1) return n;

    return binary(n >> 1) * 10 + n % 2;
}
```

It returns an `int` and it will return `binary form of the number`. *This code will **fail** to provide correct output after the number `1023`.* The binary of 1023 is 1111111111.

After this, any number you enter will cause *overflow issues* and you will receive a wrong output. You can further increase the range of the program if you  use `long`. However, that too will fail to provide any correct output after `524287` for the same reasons mentioned before.

*You can use `BigInteger` class if you want to store binary of any numbers bigger than 524287.*

Comment: You are welcome. *Do comment for any further problems related to the solution.*